# How to replace MultiColumnText with ColumnText in iText

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have such statements in the code

```
MultiColumnText mct = new MultiColumnText(MultiColumnText.AUTOMATIC);
mct.AddRegularColumns(document.Left, document.Right, 30f, 2);
mct.AddElement(table);
```

But after upgrade iText to 5.3.3 they have removed MultiColumnText and suggest use ColumnText instead!

What way to rewrite this code with ColumnText

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples available. Look for the keyword [ColumnText](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=59).

See for instance this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=68

The code you need looks like this:

```
float middle = (document.left() + document.right()) / 2;
float[][] columns = {
        { document.left(), document.bottom(), middle - 15, document.top() } ,
        { middle + 15, document.bottom(), document.right(), document.top() }
};

ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.addElement(table);
int column = 0;
int status = ColumnText.START_COLUMN;
while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
  ct.setSimpleColumn(
    COLUMNS[column][0], columns[column][1],
    COLUMNS[column][2], columns[column][3]);
  status = column.go();
  if (++count > 1) {
    count = 0;
    document.newPage();
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I use your code in c#? I don't have for example "ColumnText.START_COLUMN"

Comment: The value of `ColumnText.START_COLUMN` is `0`, so if you use `0`, it should work.